# What are all the gamerule commands in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to know what are the gamerule commands in Minecraft, and what do they do?

I want to have special stuff without using mods and plugins!

Comment: I believe this is far too broad to be properly answered.  What, exactly, are you attempting to achieve?

Comment: Vanilla Minecraft does not have many commands. [Link](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Commands)

Comment: You can find the `/gamerule` commands on the Minecraft Wiki using the link provided by Cresh. Alternatively, the [Command Block page](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Command_Block#Gamerules) has the `gamerule`s formatted nicely in a table.

Answer (score 35):

On the [Command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command#gamerule) and [Command Block](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block) page on the Minecraft Wiki, there are lists and tables describing the `/gamerule` command.

> - `commandBlockOutput` - Whether command blocks should notify admins when they perform commands.
> - `doDaylightCycle` - Toggles the day-night cycle (the sun stops moving and stays where it is) (added in [1.6.1](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Version_history#1.6.1))
> - `doEntityDrops` - Whether entities that are not mobs should have drops.
> - `doFireTick` - Whether fire should spread.
> - `doMobLoot` - Whether mobs should drop items.
> - `doMobSpawning` - Whether mobs should naturally spawn.
> - `doTileDrops` - Whether blocks should have drops.
> - `keepInventory` - Whether the player should keep items in their inventory if they die.
> - `logAdminCommands` - Whether to log admin commands to server log
> - `mobGriefing` - Whether creepers, endermen, ghasts, and withers should be able to change blocks.
> - `naturalRegeneration` - Toggles natural health regeneration
> - `randomTickSpeed` - How often a random block tick occurs (such as plant growth, leaf decay, etc.) per chunk section per game tick. 0 will disable random ticks, higher numbers will increase random ticks.
> - `reducedDebugInfo` - Whether the debug screen shows all or reduced information.
> - `sendCommandFeedback` - Whether the feedback from commands executed by a player should show up in chat. Also affects the default behavior of whether command blocks store their output text.
> - `showDeathMessages` - Whether a message appears in chat when a player dies.
>
> *Source: [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#gamerule)*

In Minecraft, you can type `/gamerule` <kbd>Tab</kbd> and keep pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to iterate through all (if no hidden ones) available game rules. When the rule you want appears, just press <kbd>Space</kbd> and input either `true` or `false`.

I believe the rule name itself is already quite self-explanatory, if not you can refer to the list above or the Minecraft Wiki or try them yourself.

Comment: Thanks! I agree most is pretty self-explanatory, but came here for the naturalRegeneration one myself. Guess that means you'll only heal through potions and such.