# What are the commands for the LAN world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've figured out that if you do `/spawnpoint` it changes your spawnpoint for the LAN world. So every time I die, I spawn where I want to. And I don't have to use my bed! I'd like to learn other commands, what are they?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97883/what-are-all-the-gamerule-commands-in-minecraft

Answer (score 7):

All the commands are available when you type <kbd>/</kbd> and keep pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>. It will loop through all available commands. And if you are good enough, you can figure out what a command does and how to use it by judging from its name.

You can also use the command `/help <page>`. It will show you all the commands available with a simple description. You can also do `/help <command>` to show the specific help of a command.

There's no explicit need of looking up the Minecraft Wiki every time you want to use a command unless you are really messed up and need some clarifications on the commands. I believe a quick glance of the wiki page will be enough.

Comment: I should also note that this answer is the better out of all the other answer as all other answer only refer to Vanilla commands. some mods can add new commands and using `/help` will reveal these commands as well

Answer (score 4):

All the commands are listed [on the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands), along with which game modes they work in.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want some of the basic commands, the most basic are,
/time set day
/effect (playername) minecraft:(the effect you want) (the amount of time) (and the power)max 250
/setworldspawn which you have figured out
these are the three most basic but there are tons of other commands.
I hope this helped.

Answer (score -2):

```
/achievement
/ban
/ban-ip
/banlist
/blockdata
/clear
/clone
/debug
/defaultgamemode
/deop
/difficulty
/effect
/enchant
/entitydata
/execute
/fill
/gamemode
/gamerule
/give
/help
/kick
/kill
/list
/me
/op
/pardon
/particle
/playsound
/publish
/replaceitem
/save-all
```

~ Page 2 ~

```
/save-off
/save-on
/say
/scoreboard
/seed
/setblock
/setidletimeout
/setworldspawn
/spawnpoint
/spreadplayers
/stats
/stop
/summon
/tell
/tellraw
/testfor
/testforblock
/testforblocks
/time
/title
/toggledownfall
/tp
/trigger
/weather
/whitelist
/worldborder
/xp
```

Answer (score -3):

- /gamerule (enter gamerule)
- /effect
- /me (action)
- /time set (enter military time)
- /spawn
- /spawnpoint
- /help (page 1-3)
- /kill
- /punish (player name) (number of hearts)

Comment: Minecraft's `/time set` command doesn't use military time. Unless the military has lately redifined noon to be 6 o'clock and multiplied everything by ten when I wasn't looking.