# How do you prevent other players from using commands?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to de-op players in Minecraft so they can't use any commands to go into creative mode and grief my map. I want to block them from using commands). How do you do that?

Comment: You don't normally *need* to de-op players. If other players on your server or LAN game have op powers, you did something to give them op powers. How you de-op them depends on how you gave them op powers in the first place. What kind of server/world is this, and how are other players getting into it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are all the gamerule commands in Minecraft?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97883/what-are-all-the-gamerule-commands-in-minecraft)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a vanilla server, the command is `/deop playername`.