# Why does /gamerule KeepInventory true not work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am in minecraft 1.8.9, and when I try to do `/gamerule KeepInventory true`, it says the command has been updated, and then I go and do /kill. But I still lose my items, both in creative and in survival. What am I doing wrong?

@Arperum mentioned in the comments that it should be `keepInventory`, but on some worlds, when I type `/gamerule` and cycle through the rules, the one with the uppercase "K" shows up. Is that a glitch?

Comment: Do you type `keepInventory` or `KeepInventory`? Your question seems to indicate that you type the second option. And it needs the first option

Comment: really? because i thought it was the second option... but it worked when i tried it, but didn't save

Comment: i just went cycled through it and is is the second option

Comment: on some worlds it is the second option

Comment: must be a glitch..

Comment: @HarryB777 It's not a glitch. I explained it in my answer, so I added it to your question since comments are supposed to be temporary and it's an interesting addition.

Answer (score 11):

The gamerule to keep your inventory is `keepInventory`, with a lower case "k"

```
/gamerule keepInventory true
```

You can look up the available gamerules on the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command#gamerule) or in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/97883/what-are-all-the-gamerule-commands-in-minecraft) (which is basically copying the wiki).

The "glitch" you are observing isn't one. Since 1.8, the game allows you to add any arbitrary gamerule. Normally, these don't do anything, but you can add actual functionality via command blocks. What you are observing on some worlds is most likely that you already set `KeepInventory` to `true`, making it a valid gamerule in that particular world, hence it shows up for auto-complete.

Answer (score 2):

First, ensure that you are OP on the server or you have cheats enabled on Singleplayer. Type `/give @p minecraft:command_block`. Go onto Creative by typing `/gamemode 1` in chat and then right click on the ground to place the command block. Open it up, and type `gamerule keepInventory true` make sure the capitals are exactly the same (e.g. not `keepinventory` or `KeepInventory`) and press `Done`. Power it via a means of redstone. In chat you should see something like: `[@: Gamerule keepInventory set to true.]`

Comment: Why would you need a command block for that?

Comment: @MrLemon You wouldn't. Some servers block gamerule commands with plugins, so, if he's is on one like that, he would have to use a command block. Source: Ex-server admin.

Comment: i just wanted to do it in single player, and i know how to do it, but thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Didn't work for me so tried `gamerule keepInventory false` then tried `gamerule keepInventory true` and it worked then.